# Review menu shows red dot, but is empty (again)

Tags: bug

Iz is basically like here [New Review Queue: Faulty Red Dot!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/new-review-queue-faulty-red-dot)

[image: Review menu]

But the queues are all empty

But as the the question above is from 2017 it is a new problem probably

Comment: have you tried CTRL + F5 to reload the page?

Comment: yes i have reloade3d the page switched between different SE sites and metas

Comment: maybe clear the browser cache?

Comment: yes that seems to do it, i never seen a red dot here before, thx

Comment: i have the same phenomena with the close votes for days it has a red dot which remains, despite all my efforts to clear it. Also the review icon gets also a red dot, without any queue having a review.

Comment: hm and now it os gone again, could it be realted that the queues have "too much" reviews in it, even when i can't review them any more

Comment: an today it  is again the close votes that gets the red dot, with an empty queue

Comment: and again with close review

Comment: and today again with the close review, it seems still like a bug